# When does a duration of 1 round end?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells

The title pretty much says it all. I am wondering when a spell with a duration of 1 round end? Does the round start directly after my turn, allowing me to have another turn before the spell ends, or is my turn accounted for in the duration?

Comment: Probably a dupe of [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/107827/52137) which marked a dupe of [this other question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/87752/52137).

Comment: Actually looking at it again, I think this a duplicate (covered as part of that question) of the latter and have marked it as such. If that doesn't answer the question for you, do please clarify how.

Comment: Did you have a specific spell in mind? The various spells with a duration of 1 round mostly specify when they end, though these are not always the same times